# A " triple-sum-free " sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, asymptotics, sieve-theory

Consider the strictly increasing integer sequence $f(n)$ defined as :

$$f(1) = 1$$

$ M $ is in the list If and only if $M$ is not of the form $ f(a) + f(b) + f(c) $ for Some integers $a,b,c > 0$.

So the sequence starts as

$$1,2,7,8,...$$

This resembles the A-sequence.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/A-Sequence.html

What is known about $f(n) $ ? 
In particular : How fast does $f(n)$ grow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence continues  $$1,2,7,8,13,14,19,20,...,6n+1,6n+2,...$$

The integers in the sequence are all of the form either $6n+1$ or $6n+2$. When these are added together in threes the sums that can be made are restricted to the forms $6n+3,6n+4,6n+5$ and $6n$. Since all such positive integers can be made, none of these appear in the sequence. Conversely, integers of the form $6n+1$ and $6n+2$ can never be the result of a sum.

Hence the sequence contains all positive integers of the form $6n+1$ and $6n+2$ and no others. Therefore, the function grows linearly.

Comment: Calling the growth rate as “constant” seems unnecessarily confusing. The function grows linearly.

Comment: @StellaBiderman Yes, of course. I've edited that.

Comment: There will be a follow-up question ...